# How to partition by LIST COLUMNS / RANGE COLUMNS in MySQL Workbench partition tab?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Looks like an option to partition by LIST COLUMNS or RANGE COLUMNS in MySQL Workbench partition tab is not available or am I missing something?
Is there any format/syntax in order to accomplish this? or it's just not available.

A workaround is to generate an SQL from the model and modify it but I wanted to do it in MySQL Workbench without doing any workaround. Is there any way to accomplish this?

PS: I was trying to partition by COLUMNS, see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

LIST and RANGE are available for **Partition by**:

[image]

Comment: That is only for LIST partitioning, I am looking for partitioning by COLUMNS. see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns.html

Comment: I can't see find it either in MySQLWorkbench. They are not listed in its documentation either. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-partitioning-tab.html